# how to force npm install command prioritize nexus npm registry over downloading from internet?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nexus, nexus3

when I run npm install to download packages for my node.js project at first it look ups internet instead of my nexus repository to download pakages to build my project. i set .npmrc in my project config and all credentials are ok for access.my question is how to force npm install command prioritize nexus npm registry over downloading from internet ?

Comment: can you share npmrc file?

Comment: impossible to answer without the npmrc file, you can obscure the authToken and share it here

Comment: the problem was actually internet access on my nexus server , so now my question is how to download them locally and whenever the server dont have internet access it download them from hosted repository?